# Método para extraer un dato de sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

Estoy comenzando con el tema de la base de datos pero aún no me familiarizó muy bien con el tema, quiero crear un método que me devuelva la cantidad de entradas en una tabla, se que el comando en sqlite es `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla` tabla pero no sé cómo extraerlo a java PC, no Android

Comment: Es para Android o para correr en otro sistema operativo?

Comment: Actualice es para otros sistemas operativos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más básica usando jdbc, es obtener un cursor sobre la ejecución del query.
Este query traerá un solo resultado, por lo que debes moverte a la primera posición del cursor y estraer el dato de ahi.

```
// conn es la conexión abierta a la base de datos
    public void correrUnQuery(Connection conn) throws SQLException{
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) CANT FROM tabla");

      // Si hay es un solo resultado, si hubiera más en lugar del `if` habría que usar un `while`.

      int cant = -1;
      if(rs.next()){
        cant = rs.getString("CANT");
      }

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();

      System.out.println((cant == -1 ? "No hay registros", "Hay " + cant + "registros"));
    }
```

Nota: Este query o falla o siempre trae un resultado, incluí el `if` para que lo tengas como referencia si la consulta puede no traer resultados.